# Will `std::vector` do anything I haven't asked it to

Tags: c++, vector, capacity

In C++, if I initialize a `std::vector v(100);` and never try to `resize()` nor `reserve()` it, is the `capacity()` guaranteed to stay the same all the time? I want to make sure that no memory alloc/freeing/realloc/etc is going on for perforance reasons. (Yes, it would affect performance; my functions are called all the time, and they *must* returrn quickly).

Resuming it all:

```
std::vector<float> v;
// somehow, `v' is initialized to have 100 elements
void f() { // this function must return _very_ quickly
    /* do some processing, without ever calling v.resize() or v.reserve(), but
       accesing v.size() and v[i] all the time */
    /* it is guaranteed that no system calls (such as memory management)
       will take place here? */
} // no objects on the stack whose destroyers might try to `delete' anything.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the remarks on `vector::reserve()` in C++11 23.3.6.3 "vector capacity":

> It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions
>   that happen after a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion
>   would make the size of the vector greater than the value of
>   `capacity()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is vector::data() exposing the array allocated. Hence it is fair to assume that any operation on the vector equivalent to any modification on vector::data() will not effect memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Any non-const operation on the vector might modify it. Any O(n) operation (like push_back) on the vector may cause the underlying data to be relocated. You can click into the various pages on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to see what the big-Oh notation is for the operations you intend to use.

Calls to size and the subscript operator must complete in O(1) time, and so the vector would not reallocate its buffer.